# Not able to display the object array values in the dynamically inserted view using angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have just started to learn AngularJS.
I am trying to write this code with 3 files index.html and view1.html and view2.html .  In index.html I have defined the module and controller function.In the controller 'sc' i have javascript object array with 2 fields name and city harcoded. I have used the router functionality to add a new view which will be used to search by the user and i have also added a button to dynamically insert a new pair of values into the object array.

But i am unable to print the name and city values in the view1 and view2. I am sure there is some problem with the scope but i am unable to find the error.

## Below is the index.html file code.

```html
<html ng-app="demo" >
    <head>
        <title>AngularStuff!!!</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    </head>
    <body  >
       <!-- <div ng-controller='sc'>
        </div>-->
       <div ng-controller="sc"> 
       <div ng-view=" "></div>
       </div> 
       <script>
            var demo=angular.module('demo',['ngRoute']);
            
            demo.controller('sc',function($scope){
                
                
                
                $scope.customers=[
                    {name:'Johnny',city:'ab'},
                    {name:'Jane',city:'ab'},
                    {name:'Apple',city:'tv'},
                    {name:'Clarice',city:'ku'},
                    {name:'Clayton',city:'lm'}
        
                                ];
                
               
            $scope.add=function()
            {
                
              $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.n.name,city:$scope.n.city}) ; 
                
                
            };
             
                
                
            }
             
            
            );
          
    
     
    demo.config(
                   
            
            function($routeProvider)
                        {
                            $routeProvider
                                    .when('/',
                                               
                                        {     
                                                
                                                controller:'sc',
                                                templateUrl:'View1.html'
                
                
                
                                        }
                                          )
                                          .when('/View2',
                                         {
                                               controller:'sc',           
                                               templateUrl:'View2.html'
                
                
                                          }
                
                
                                       )
                                  
                                  
                            
                            
                            
                                     .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
                            
         
        
    }
            
            
            
            
            
            ); 
    
   
   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Below is the view1.html File Code

```html
  
<div >
        
            <h2 align="center">View1</h2>
            
            Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"/>
            
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in cutomers|filter:filter.name">                    
                    {{cust.name}}--{{cust.city}}
</li>
            </ul>
        Customer Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="n.name"/>
        <br/>
        
        Customer City:
        <input type="text" ng-model="n.city"/>
        
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="add()">Add Customer</button>
        <a href="View2.html">View2</a>
        </div>
```

## Below is the view2.html

```html
  
<div >
        
            <h2 align="center">View1</h2>
            
            Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"/>
            
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in cutomers|filter:filter.name">                    
                    {{cust.name}}--{{cust.city}}
</li>
            </ul>
        Customer Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="n.name"/>
        <br/>
        
        Customer City:
        <input type="text" ng-model="n.city"/>
        
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="add()">Add Customer</button>
        <a href="View2.html">View2</a>
        </div>
```

The views are loading properly but the values are not getting displayed.[image: below the first input 'Name' tab the object array values name and city are not getting dispalyed]

Comment: why are you doing |filter:filter.name? What is filter.name in your ng-repeat?

Comment: i tried using name1 instead of filter.repeat but still the problem is same. filter.name takes the input values from the user and using it searches the object array customers and displays the relevant results.

Comment: You made a typo in your html. You do an `ng-repeat` over `cutomers`, but it is called `customers` on your `$scope`

Comment: @devqon Thanks for your help . I was struck in this mess since morning and couldnot spot this silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:cust.name">                    
                    {{cust.name}} {{cust.city}}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tOgKIbwSnA493Vj7351Z)